# Requirements for a Simple Post-Collision Path Analysis

Tags: collision

A wheel of mass $m_2$ is attached to the end of a rod of length *L* and mass $m_1$. The rod is pulled in the x-axis by a prismatic joint with a constant velocity *V*. The rod is attached to both the wheel and the prismatic joint with a revolute joint.

[image]

While the system is in motion, the wheel collides with a bump of height *h* and width *w*. I have two questions here:

1. Can the path of the wheel (how far it will travel vertically and horizontally) be physically determined after the collision? If yes, what theorems can I use?
2. As seen in the figure, there are two configurations: a) wide initial angle-*θ* and b) narrow initial angle-*β*. All remaining system parameters are the same. After the collision, in which configuration will the wheel go higher, and in which one will it fall further?